# What is the D C T E R M of following linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, linear-transformations

Let T : $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ to $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ be the linear transformation then what will be the determinant, trace, characteristic polynomial,eigen values, rank and minimal polynomial of following linear transformation:

$(1)$ $T(A)=BA $,  for any fixed matrix $B\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$

$(2)$ $T(A)=AB$,  for any fixed matrix $B\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$

$(3)$ $T(A)=BA+AB$,  for any fixed matrix $B\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$

$(4)$ $T(A)=BA-AB$,  for any fixed matrix $B\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$

(5) $T(A)=AB-BA$,  for any fixed matrix $B\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$

I tried, for particular case  $n=2$ the determinant and trace of $(1),(2)$ is $\operatorname{trace} T=2(\operatorname{trace} B)$ and $ \det T=(\det B)^2$. Is it hold for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$?

For $(3)$ $\operatorname{trace} T=4(\operatorname{trace} B)$ and $ \det T=4(\det B)(\det B)^2$ In general, is it true that $\operatorname{trace} T=n^2(\operatorname{trace} B)$? and what about determinant?

For  $(4),(5)$ trace and determinant is zero. Once I know the determinant I can find relation between eigen values of A and B. I know idea about minimal polynomial. **If the question partially discussed in this site one can send the link on comment box**. I want to know that the thing holds in particular case of $n$ for $T$, Is it hold in general? Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please consider to use \operatorname{trace} (=$\operatorname{trace}$) instead of trace (=$trace$).

Comment: I tried it but that indicate me red line.

Comment: use \operatorname{trace}